# Tight bounds on the partial Möbius sum $\sum_{\substack{d|n\\d<Q}}\mu(d)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

An important area of study in Analytic Number Theory is the behavior of the Möbius function $\mu(n)$. I was trying to prove a different theorem when I came about a very interesting behavior. If you look at the partial sums of the sum of the Möbius function over the divisors of $n$, namely

$$A_Q(n)=\sum_{\substack{d|n\\d<Q}}\mu(d)$$

We see extraordinary cancelling. If we take $Q$ to larger than the maximum divisor than $n$ then of course this sum will be $0$ for $n>1$, but I would still have expected large partial sums. If we define

$$\omega_Q(n)=\sum_{\substack{p|n\\p<Q}}1$$

to be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ less than $Q$, then my conjecture is that there exists an integer $k$ such that

$$\left| A_Q(n)\right|=O\left(\omega_Q(n)^k\right)$$

There is strong numerical evidence to back this up. I have experimentally seen that, for a given count $j$ of prime factors less than $Q$, $\left| A_Q(n)\right|$ finds its largest values when $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_j$ is the product of the first $j$ primes. I then used Desmos to create the best-fit cubic which has an $r^2$ value of $.999$: It is essentially a perfect fit. This means that is highly probable that

$$A_Q(n)=O\left(\omega_Q(n)^3\right)$$

but even proving that it is polynomial in $\omega_Q(n)$ is difficult. Does anyone have any ideas or know of any papers that discuss this topic?

Comment: Can you share the Desmos calculation?

Comment: @joriki Sure: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vuktiwjmwi

Comment: How did you choose $Q$ for that calculation? (Nice question by the way, $+1$.)

Comment: @joriki I ran a python program and saw the value with maximum absolute value: do you want me to send you the code?

Comment: That would be great. (You can post it e.g. on http://gist.github.com if it's too much to include here.)

Comment: @joriki 
#evaluate A_Q(n) where n is an array of distinct prime factors using recursion techniques
def A(Q,n):
 length=len(n)

 if Q==2:
  return 1
 
 n = [p for p in n if p<Q]

 if len(n)==0:
  return 1

 return A(Q,n[:-1])-A(-((-Q)//n[-1]),n[:-1])

#our number
S=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31]

#find maximum value we need to check
MAX = 1
for s in S:
 MAX*=s

#check our values and print every time we find a larger one
V0=0
for Q in range(1,MAX+2):
 V=A(Q,S)
 if abs(V)>abs(V0):
  V0=abs(V)
  print(str(Q)+": "+str(V))

Comment: @joriki I will put it on github too since the formatting is messed up here

Comment: @joriki Here is the link: https://gist.github.com/ShwiftyMomo/0339e1e7a651edd3bb371eab1eaf5100

Comment: Thanks! You can get syntax highlighting if you use a filename with the right ending (.py in this case).

Comment: Just a thought; I'm not sure how relevant this is, but it draws a connection to another phenomenon with a suprising (even greater) amount of cancellation: Pretend that the logarithms of the primes are evenly spaced (which of course they aren't). For simplicity, scale them so they're the positive integers. Then you're counting the partitions into distinct parts of numbers below $\log Q$ according to the parity of the number of parts, i.e the excess of the partitions with even numbers of distinct parts over those with odd numbers of distinct parts.

Comment: The generating function for these is $\prod_n(1-x^n)$, which according to the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) has almost complete cancellation and coefficients with absolute value at most $1$. Summing up to $\log Q$ (corresponding to dividing the generating function by $1-x$) again yields coefficients with absolute value at most $1$.

Comment: @joriki thank you so much for working on this. I've been stuck thinking about this for two weeks now and I need this result to move forward with the main math project I'm working on right now so this is really so appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108500/discussion-between-milo-moses-and-joriki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is no polynomial bound in terms of $\omega_Q(n)$. Namely, this happens if one chooses all of the primes to be "equal". This isn't possible but in practice one can choose groups of primes that are arbitrarily tightly packed with respect to their size, see [here][1], which gets us the same results.

If all of the primes are equal then we can choose $Q$ such that any group of $j$ primes is less than $Q$ but any group of $j+1$ primes is greater than $Q$, and thus by counting the number of divisors of $n$ with any given number of prime factors less than $j$ signed according to the Mobius function we see that

$$A_Q(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{j}{ {\omega_Q(n)}\choose{k}}(-1)^{k}$$

For large values of $j$ this sum will be dominated by it's last term, namely

$$A_Q(n)=(1-o(1)){ {\omega_Q(n)}\choose{j}}(-1)^j$$

where the $o(1)$ is with respect to $j$. We can thus get the sharp bound (in terms of $\omega_Q(n)$) that

\begin{equation}
|A_Q(n)|<{ {\omega_Q(n)}\choose{\omega_Q(n)/2}}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

since $j=\omega_Q(n)/2$ maximizes ${ {\omega_Q(n)}\choose{j}}$. Using more complex methods one can rigorously show that this is indeed the best bound, and that (1) always holds. Using stirling's approximation on (1) we get that

\begin{equation}
|A_Q(n)|<\frac{2^{\omega_Q(n)}}{\sqrt{\omega_Q(n)}}
\end{equation}

which is a much more useful bound. Namely, it can get us results about the quantity $\mathbf{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[|A_Q(n)|\right]$. The trivial bound by counting terms gives us that

$$\mathbf{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[|A_Q(n)|\right]<\frac{6}{\pi^2}\log(Q)$$

but using this new bound we can improve this to

$$\mathbf{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[|A_Q(n)|\right]<C\frac{\log(Q)}{\sqrt{\log(\log(Q))}}$$

EDIT: It turns out that the true bound (the proof is too long to include here) is that

$$\mathbf{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[|A_Q(n)|\right]<c_0$$

for some absolute constant $c_0$
[1]: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/Maynard.pdf